# Appropriate copyleft license for translation files

Tags: licensing, gpl, license-recommendation, copyleft, cc-by-sa

I'm using a GPL license (with an AppStore exception) for my app and CC BY-SA for the images used in the app, as I know the GPL isn't appropriate for artwork.

However, I'm wondering what I should license translation files under (and ask contributors to license their translations under too). Is the GPL appropriate for translations, or would CC BY-SA be a better fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The translations are usually a part of the programme and translations hardly fit another context. So that's a good reason to license them under the same terms as the rest - and it saves you licensing troubles.

Graphics assets often are treated differently as they might both come from different sources as well be used in entirely different context. Additionally they cannot be treated textually as translations can. Both makes a CC-BY-whatever license more appropriate for graphics.